# Can't get PIL to work on Mac OS X

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wanted to recompile `PIL` after having installed `libjpeg` because it threw the `decoder jpeg not available` whenever I tried importing JPEG images.

So, I've downloaded `libjpeg`, compiled it and installed it. Then I removed the `./build` folder from PIL's source cache, and recompiled it (using `sudo python setup.py install`).

Now the `selftest.py` thing is failing with `*** The _imaging C module is not installed`. **I have no idea what the issue is.**

- There are no symbol errors.
- The `_imaging` module is importable
- All dylibs are loaded properly (according to `-v`)
- The decoder error is still there.

*Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm on OS X Lion.*

Comment: what python version are you using? and which version of PIL?

Comment: Did you compile the PIL the same way as libjpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would I try:

- Remove old PIL and install new it from scratch (maybe it did not override properly).
- If you missed something when compiling the libjpeg, like path specifications it will not find some of the libraries, so I recomend trying MacPorts **py27-pil** port for PIL installation, which will place all dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem with

```
pip install Pillow
```